# Integration by Parts is the 'reverse product rule'. Is there a quotient equivalent?

Tags: integration

As the title suggests. I do understand that the quotient rule is pretty much the product rule combined with the chain rule, but regardless is there a methodical way of computing such integrals?

Comment: [Also useful](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/switkes01200543268.pdf).